# Punctuation in commutative diagrams

Tags: punctuation, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm using many commutative diagrams in my notes and I'm trying to punctuate them, as any other mathematical object. Now I have two questions on how to achieve the right punctuation.

When the period is written carelessly some diagrams don't look right. For example, in the following diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\ar{d}\\
C\ar{r} & D,
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the comma produces a wider node and the right arrow doesn't look centered anymore. For that matter, I'm adding `\phantom{,}` to node `B`, but it doesn't seem very practical. So, the first question is there is a good way to fix the spacing in the above diagram.

The second question is about styling. In a diagram like the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\\
C\ar{ur}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

where should I add punctuation? In C, B or after the diagram? I have not found anything in the [AMS style guide](https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/index.html).

---

**EDIT**
I'm using as reference two books of Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician* and *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, in which there is punctuation in diagrams.

Now, I'm giving a more detailed look at the diagrams and what I see is that he avoids the diagrams like the triangle above (as suggested by egreg) and when they cannot be avoided they are not punctuated (like daleif suggest).

Comment: In a situation like this I'd see the diagram as a piece of gfx and thus **not** add punctuation it does not make much sense and may lead to confusion.

Comment: If you insist, `\makebox[0pt][l]{,}` should do for the first diagram. For the second one, I see no sensible place where to put the punctuation. Find a way to avoid it.

Comment: For the triangle type diagram, see the diagram after equation 4 in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, which is on page 16 if we have the same edition. There the punctuation is after the lowermost character.

Comment: I would put it at `C`, which is the “last line” in a certain sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools` (a superset of `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\ar{d}\\
C\ar{r} & D\mathrlap{,}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Standard practice seems to be just not to put punctuation after a commutative diagram, even if a period or comma would otherwise belong at that point in the sentence. I looked at a few papers just now and they all seemed to do it that way.

However, if you can't live without punctuation another option is to just put the punctuation after the tikzcd environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\ar{d}\\
        C\ar{r} & D
    \end{tikzcd},
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is admittedly somewhat ugly, but it has the advantage that it works logically for the triangle diagram as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\\
        C\ar{ur}
    \end{tikzcd},
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I eddited my original question to add some books in which there is punctuation in diagrams. Is there a reason to suggest to put the comma after the `tikzcd` environment? I feel it looks odd

Comment: There's no great reason to suggest it, other than it being an alternative position for punctuation that might make sense. It does look a bit odd to my eyes as well.